# The hash of kali-linux-2022.4-raspberry-pi-arm64.img.xz changed after burning it into an sd card

Tags: hash, sha256

I was burning an iso file into the sd card with pi imager and I doubled checked the hash before the burning and after and I got different results

```
sha256sum kali-linux-2022.4-raspberry-pi-arm64.img.xz
fba37da4901558479de64fd886937e3d4653e9a9439e3636a553eab2a5e9a739  kali-linux-2022.4-raspberry-pi-arm64.img.xz

sha256sum kali-linux-2022.4-raspberry-pi-arm64.img.xz
60e33582746bb25d87092e842398e1f946ff3cd3678743856f01d8bd3b43946a  kali-linux-2022.4-raspberry-pi-arm64.img.xz
```

Comment: Then of course the result will change

Comment: can i ask why it will change ?

Comment: Because you are *installing* it, not copying it. There will be slight modifications from the base file.